# Jquery : Do something before navigation onclick

Tags: jquery

I am developing a website. In my website there are 5 menus. 5 menus corresponds to five different html pages. But it seems that it is single page. This property is achieved by [pjax plugin](http://pjax.heroku.com/) (pjax loads html into the current page without a full page load.)

Html of menus

```
<div id="header-menu">
  <a href="index.html">
    <div id="logo-container"> 
     <img src="img/logo.png" />         
    </div >
  </a>
<div id="menu-container">
  <a href="whatvdo.html">
    <div id="menu1">         
      <p class="menuitemslb">What we do?</p>        
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="whovr.html">
    <div id="menu2">    
      <p class="menuitemslb">Who we are?</p>     
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="howvwork.html">
    <div id="menu3">
      <p class="menuitemslb">How we work?</p>
    </div>
 </a>
 <a href="createnewapp.html">
     <div id="menu4">
       <p class="menuitemslb">Create a project!</p>
     </div>
 </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Script to invoke pjax:

```
$(function(){
  $('div#header-menu a').pjax('#master-div')
 })
```

Animation to content divs is done using following script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $("#contenttotal").css("top", "-100px").animate( { "opacity": "show", "top":"25px"} , "slow" );
            $("#whatvdo").hide();
            $("#createnewapp").hide();
            $("#whovr").hide();
            $("#howvwnew").hide();      

            $("#menu1").click(function(){
                $("#whatvdo").css("top", "-100px").animate( { "opacity": "show", "top":"25px"} , "slow" );  
                $("#contenttotal").hide();          
                $("#createnewapp").hide();  
                $("#whovr").hide();             
                $("#howvwnew").hide();              
            });


            $("#logocontainer").click(function(){
                $("#contenttotal").css("top", "-200px").animate( { "opacity": "show", "top":"0px"} , "slow" );  
                $("#createnewapp").hide();
                $("#whatvdo").hide();   
                $("#whovr").hide(); 
                $("#howvwnew").hide();                              
            });

        $("#menu4").click(function(){
                $("#createnewapp").css("top", "-200px").animate( { "opacity": "show", "top":"0px"} , "slow" );  
                    $("#whatvdo").hide();               
                    $("#contenttotal").hide();      
                    $("#whovr").hide();     
                    $("#howvwnew").hide();              
            });

            $("#menu2").click(function(){
                $("#whovr").css("top", "-200px").animate( { "opacity": "show", "top":"0px"} , "slow" );  
                    $("#whatvdo").hide();               
                    $("#contenttotal").hide();              
                    $("#createnewapp").hide();  
                    $("#howvwnew").hide();              
            });

            $("#menu3").click(function(){
                $("#howvwnew").css("top", "-200px").animate( { "opacity": "show", "top":"0px"} , "slow" );  
                    $("#whatvdo").hide();               
                    $("#contenttotal").hide();              
                    $("#createnewapp").hide();              
                    $("#whovr").hide();             
            });

        });
```

My problem is that, now when i click on each menu the current content div vanishes and go to corresponding page. before the div vanishes i want to perform an animation. How is that possible?

Please refer [my site](http://applicate.co.nz/website/index.html)

Please help,
Thank you.

Comment: callback functions may solve your issue

Comment: I'm guessing you would have to figure out how to load the content without a plugin to make it work with animations, unless the plugin somehow supports animation (don't know pjax).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with one of your menu click events.  The elements you want to hide won't be hidden until after the animation is finished and the `complete` callback is performed.

```
        $("#menu1").click(function(){
            $("#whatvdo").css("top", "-100px").animate( { 
                 "opacity": "show", 
                 "top":"25px"
               } , {
                 duration: "slow",
                 complete: function() {
                   $("#contenttotal").hide();          
                   $("#createnewapp").hide();  
                   $("#whovr").hide();             
                   $("#howvwnew").hide();              
               }
            });
        });
```

I noticed you had a lot of repetitious code you can change the call back to something simpler like:

```
complete: function() { 
   $("#contenttotal, #createnewapp, #whovr, #howvwnew").hide(); 
}
```

Or create a function specific to your purpose:

```
function hideAllExcept(exception) {
     $("#whatvdo, #contenttotal, #createnewapp, #whovr, #howvwnew")
       .not( + exception + ).hide(); 
}

// in animate:
complete: function() { hideAllExcept('#whatvdo'); }
```

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear. I meant that,i want to perform another animation  to current content div, when click on the next menu before navigation?